# A single die is rolled 7 times. What is the probability that a six is rolled exactly once, if it is known that at least one six is rolled?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A single die is rolled 7 times. What is the probability that a six is rolled exactly once, if it is known that at least one six is rolled?

Could you walk me through the concepts?

Comment: Count the number of outcomes where a six is rolled exactly once, and divide by the number of outcomes where at least one six is rolled. (For the denominator, it might be easier to count the number of outcomes where no sixes are rolled, and subtract that from the total number of outcomes.)

Comment: So, the probability of rolling at least one six would be 1 - (5/6)^7 and the probability of rolling one six would be (1/6)(5/6)^6? So, you would divide those two numbers?

Comment: So, is the answer 0.0774?

Comment: Almost: the latter probability should be $7(1/6)(5/6)^6$; the extra factor of 7 is to account for the fact that the only six that you roll could appear on the first roll, or on the second roll, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $P(\text{exactly one } 6) $, the denominator should be the total number of outcomes, which is $6^7$. Looking at the outcomes with one $6$, there are seven slots to put the 6. From the remaining six slots, there are $5^6$ possible outcomes. Hence,
$$
P(\text{exactly one } 6)=\frac{7\times5^6}{6^7}.
$$
For $P(\text{at least one } 6)$, use the complement law. The answer is then
\begin{align}
P(\text{exactly one }6|\text{at least one }6)&=\frac{P(\text{exactly one }6\text{ and at least one }6)}{P(\text{at least one }6)} \\
&=\frac{P(\text{exactly one }6)}{P(\text{at least one }6)}.
\end{align}

Comment: P(exactly one 6) = 7(1/6)(5/6)^6 and P(at least one 6) = 1 - (5/6)^7. So, it's 0.3907/0.7209 which is 0.54196? Is this correct?